# Coded UI test cases not running on 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have created some test cases in Coded UI on 32-bit machine and now I have got another machine for running these test cases (which is 64 bit machine), when I executed my test cases using that machine, they got failed and error message 
is shown.

> Result Message:    The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data
>   source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting
>   this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests"
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.
>   Error details: ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The
>   specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and
>   Application

On further investigating I found a lot of links and came to know that this is because of 32-bit and 64-bit issue, I also found that this can be resolved by specifying 32-bit as Platform Target in the Build tab of the project properties, **but this too doesn't work for me**.

Let me know how this issue can be resolved. Office 2013 is installed on both machines.

I am using Excel files as the data source and connection string looks like this.

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=C:\\Data1.xls;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

These are the links which I already referred to:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365146/error-the-specified-dsn-contains-anarchitecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-an
2. https://dacosta9.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/error-im014-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application/
3. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/097ff93d-20be-41ed-b318-dc51cca0b811/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application?forum=wcf